# Возможно ли написать сайт, используя только С#?

Tags: asp.net, c#

Здравствуйте, как у начинающего программиста в сфере "intenet" возник вопрос. 
Понимая, что можно создать сайт использую `php + apache + linux` (все это на стороне сервера), хотел обойти это, использовать все прелести microsoft'a и создавать, использую asp технологию. И наконец вопрос: что надо для этого использовать в обязательном случае использую язык с#?

Comment: На самом деле, можно создать сайт, используя только С )))

Comment: я с большой уверенностью могу сказать что на с# тоже можно создавать использую asp.net но какие технологии нужны в данном случае вот в чем был вопрос

Answer (score 1):

Смотря что считать сайтом, но вообще asp.net (или asp.net mvc) как бы достаточно с только с# языком (или vb) для создания саита. Как минимум нужно еще html, css, javascript (jQuery) ну и смотря что еще нужно, например вместо flash можно тоже самое сделать на silverlight на c#.

Comment: базовые знания языков на клиентской стороне имеется(html and  css и приблизительно java script) но вот вопрос что надо использовать на стороне сервера(в обязательном случае использую технология microsoft'a)

Comment: Windows... на котором должен быть IIS + .NET Framework, в котором находится asp.net и все остальное + MSSQL Server. Необходимо соответствующую ОС с ИИС и поставить студию (она sql express установит вместе с framework).